# ifconfig TX/RX on gateway

Tags: linux, nat, ifconfig

I have a linux gateway which does nat for a couple of machines behind it.

I got complains that we have way more monthly traffic *gigs more* than we should so the first thing I look was check the ifconfig RX/TX stats for the network interfaces which weren't over 3 Gigs...

So do these RX/TX values also include the data traffic which was forwarded through that machine?

Even if I just check the counter states for the nat table in iptables, does only show couple of hundred megs.

Answer (score 2):

I presume your distribution is on 32 bit and your interface counter doesn't support more than 4Gigs (2^32) and after reaching this MAX value is reseting and start from 0. This is way you don't see all the traffic.

If is on 64bit then the traffic counter should be ok, if you restarted the interface in the same time with the other guys who count your traffic :)